# Microsoft Edge on Kubuntu crashes on startup

Tags: kubuntu, browser

I am using Kubuntu 22.10 and downloaded the latest Microsoft Edge Stable release from the official site. It was working well at first. But now every time I try to start the app it crashes. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Even tried the beta release but it crashes. Running it from terminal shows these error message:

```
[1229/172735.614542:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[1229/172735.615096:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: This, an error at the [`elf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) level followed by a core dump, is a bug and as such offtopic here. You might be able to report the bug somewhere though.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a problem on my end or not as it was working and started crashing suddenly. Thank you for letting me know.